# Using Python Turtle to Draw the name 'QUINN'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to help my brother with his code. He is using Python Turtle. I have enver used this before so it is brand new to me. He is trying to use turtle to draw his name 'QUINN'

I have been able to create the letter P and the letter R. I am not sure how to tackle his name though. Below is the code to create a 'P' and an 'R'. If someone could show me how to draw his name I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import turtle


t = turtle.Turtle()

t.reset()
t.pencolor('blue')
t.pensize(5)
t.penup()
t.goto(-300, 200)

# Draw The Letter 'Q'
t.pendown()
t.fd(20)
t.circle(-30, 180)
t.fd(20)
t.rt(90)
t.fd(60)
t.bk(60)
t.lt(180)
t.fd(60)

t.penup()
t.goto(-230, 200)

# Draw The Letter 'U'
t.pendown()
t.lt(90)
t.fd(20)
t.circle(-30, 180)
t.fd(20)
t.rt(90)
t.fd(60)
t.bk(60)
t.lt(180)
t.fd(60)
t.bk(60)
t.lt(45)
t.fd(80)
t.rt(45)

t.penup()
t.goto(-160, 200)

# Draw The Letter 'I'


# Draw The Letter 'N'


# Draw The Letter 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will draw the word QUINN. Some key concepts are using loops to make drawing squares such as the Q and using functions (def) to make the code cleaner and easier to read. One key aspect in this code is geometry. You must use it to make both Ns. Use the equation (hypotenuse/square root of two) if you are to use 45 or 135 degree angles. Hope this helps!

```
speed(0)
# Draw Q
def draw_q():
    penup()
    setposition(-150,0)
    color("blue")
    pendown()
    pensize(5)
    left(90)
    for i in range(4):
    forward(50)
    right(90)
    right(90)
    forward(50)
    left(135)
    backward(15)
    forward(30)
    backward(15)
    left(225)
# Draw U
def draw_u():
    pendown()
    left(90)
    forward(50)
    backward(50)
    right(90)
    forward(50)
    left(90)
    forward(50)
    backward(50)
    right(90)
# Draw I
def draw_i():
    left(90)
    forward(50)
    backward(50)
    right(90)
# Draw N twice
def draw_n():
    pendown()
    left(90)
    forward(50)
    right(135)
    forward(70.7)
    left(135)
    forward(50)
    backward(50)
    right(90)
    penup()
    forward(25)

draw_q()
penup()
forward(25)
pendown()
draw_u()
penup()
forward(25)
pendown()
draw_i()
penup()
forward(25)
pendown()
for i in range(2):
draw_n()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I just tried this solution. For some reason I am getting an error on line 11 where you have...                                                                                                                                              for i in range(4):                                                                                         forward(50)                                                                                                                  
It is saying "E112 expected an indented block"

Comment: However, If I indent it the error goes away for that line but then I get an error for the very last line 'draw_n()'. Then, if I indent that last line then every single line of code throws an error 

Comment: I have fixed the error I was getting; however, it doesnt seem like your solution creates a 'Q'. The pictures I am getting is the letters U,I,N,N stacked vertically on top of each other all connected by a line to the left of the letters.

Comment: What are you using to code? I'm using turtle in python 3

Comment: @TheQuestionist, your code is indented incorrectly. Please copy-paste the code from your answer to a Python source file and run it. You'll see that it doesn't work. You probably tested different code than what you posted here.